# Помогите! Я сделал игру, и хочу добавить звуки, но они не проигрываются. Только если по нажатию какой либо клавиши

Tags: python, pygame, mixer-music-load

```
# Для звуков
pygame.mixer.music.load("Sound/Main_music.mp3")

main_screen = True
while main_screen:
    
    # Для фоновой музыки
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

"Вот так не работает"

```
# Для звуков
pygame.mixer.music.load("Sound/Main_music.mp3")

main_screen = True
while main_screen:
    
    # Для фоновой музыки
    if press.[pygame.K_e]:
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

"А вот так работает"

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы работало нужно добавить проигрывание до основного цикла `while` а не внутри.

```
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('Sound/Main_music.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Потому что если внутри цикла `while` делать и без условий оно при каждой итерации цикла а их может быть 1000 в минуту будет пытаться начать проигрывать звук, в итоге ничего хорошего не выйдет.